# Where do images need to be stored in and Android app?

Tags: android, android-glide

I've been reading quite a lot on the topic, still not quite clear though. At the moment I'm creating an app, loading an image and a text on one screen. For loading the images I opted for Glide, but where is the most appropriate place to read them from? All of the tutorials I passed pass the image's URL. Isn't it slower when loaded from the net? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use fresco , picasso, nestrol imageloader for cache images

Comment: Glide is good tool to load images, first time it will load slow but from next time onwards it will load faster than previous time, it will cache the images.If you want to implement cache technique then you can use LRU cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care for `apk size` then do not put these images `static`. Instead you can keep these images on `server`(your or free server) and easily load those images using libraries like `Glide` or `Picasso`.

> Isn't it slower when loaded from the net?

No. It will download image once and then cache it for future use. So it's very fast.

If you think `apk size` will doesn't matter for you and user should not face problem due to unavailability of internet then you can keep those images static inside app iteself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, indramurari! May you give me an example for a free server where I can store images?

Comment: @user645677 you can store images to [aws server](aws.amazon.com/webapps) or [imgur](imgur.com/) etc. There are lot of free image hosting servers. You will get it on google too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build an app that uses dynamic images or you want to update your images without updating your application, getting them from the server is better. And in my opition picasso is easy to use and straightforward. Also uses it's own framework caching. But if you think that your images wont change, put them in an asset folder so that they are in app's internal memory. Getting them from the server has it's downsides like you need to use a placeholder images because they won't be retrieved immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You must use caching mechanisms if you want the images always from network. The system I follow is like this: (PS. I use Picasso, fast and reliable):

```
Picasso.with(this).load(URL).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).  //load from cache first time
                into(imageView, new Callback() { //Picasso Callback 
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        if(isNetworkAvailable()) { // if network available then update the cache for this URL
                            Picasso.with(MyActivity.this).invalidate(URL);
                        }
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Progressbar
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() { // Image not loaded, try again one last time
                        Picasso.with(MyActivity.this).load(URL).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code snippet, as well as for the explanations, moving to Picasso :)